# CoreData database not showing in sqlite since moving to Xcode 5

Tags: sqlite, core-data, xcode5

I have an app that uses a `CoreData` database the contents of which I view using `sqlite`. The database path is the same:

/Users/Comp1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/16226A0A-575C-4356-BFAA-6B1A009C0585/Documents

and I can see the database file. But when I open it in sqlite there appears to be no data, although I can read through the app.

It was working fine until I loaded Xcode 5. Does anyone know why this might be?

No tables shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you launch the app a second time, can you see the data in your app?

In iOS 7, SQLite now has journaling turned on. I wonder if the journalling is causing a confusion (data is there but not in the sqlite file yet).

If you see data on the second launch then don't worry about it.  The journaling just hasn't flushed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have launched and relaunched the simulator but still nothing. Can I force any of this journaling?

Comment: Yes, you can perform a vacuum on the file to force it to consume the journal files.